# Pass a single value from a List of ViewModels into a View

Tags: razor, mvvm

I have a list of ViewModels being passed in from my controller.  My view is set up with a foreach to pull in each value.  However, there is one value, my title, that I only want to pull in once, I don't want one title foreach item in my list.  How would I write that? I tried

```
<h1 class="header-title">@Model.CollectionsManagementViewModels.Select(i => i.Title)</h1>
```

but it pulls in a string

> "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Program.Models.ViewModels.CollectionsManagementViewModel,System.String]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting collection in html of `h1` tag, as `Select()` will project a new collection with just one property of whatever type is of `Title` property, you need to put `FirstOrDefault()` as a quick fix for this:

```
<h1 class="header-title">@Model.CollectionsManagementViewModels
                               .Select(i => i.Title)
                               .FirstOrDefault()
</h1>
```

or if it for sure that data will always be there, then you can use `First()` like:

```
<h1 class="header-title">@Model.CollectionsManagementViewModels
                               .First()                             
                               .Title
</h1>
```